# Google Tag Manager v2 and Cart Tracking

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, google-tag-manager

Am currently working on implementing GTM on a new online store.  I can successfully see product impressions and checkout completions in ecommerce tracking and working well.
I am now looking at the addToCart and removeFromCart events to track product conversions and having a few issues.
When the user clicks the 'Buy Now' button, an ajax request is posted to the server to add to the cart, and returns an JSON update to the browser.  It would have made some sense to intercept this response (containing product, quantity and other details) and fire off an update to GTM... but... it doesn't quite seem to work this way.
From my research it seems GTM is best suited when the dataLayer is populated before the GTM script declaration.

Is there another way to trigger off the addToCart or removeFromCart following an ajax post?  Am i missing something?

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: Have you tried doing a GTM dataLayer push of an event when the ATC or RFC buttons are clicked?

Comment: Yep I can, and can see the updated dataLayer message when debugging, but not seeing the data in GA. From what I can tell push() doesn't send the data to GA, just adds it to the array. Or am I incorrect?

Comment: Yes, you would need to use the pushed event to help trigger your GTM tags.

Comment: Thanks, but not quite sure what you mean by that... can you explain further please? The data is being added to the dataLayer - i suppose i need to trigger the update to GA somehow??

Comment: Yes, the dataLayer event should be used as a trigger in GTM to fire your Ecommerce tags. For example, on your product page, when you click the ATC button, you could push the event "addToCart" to the dataLayer on click, along with your product details (ID, name, price, quantity, etc.). In GTM, you would have an ecommerce tag that would use that event, along with the product details, to trigger the add to cart event. Check this site out for a great example: https://enhancedecommerce.appspot.com/. Click any product, and then the ATC button, while checking the dataLayer on the console.

Comment: Fantastic - thanks for the detailed answer... i will check it out this evening and report back!  Much appreciated!

Comment: Yeah - implemented GTM event to track the addToCart and i can see the cart add in GA!  Appreciate the help!!